# How to list all files are accessed by Windows Process

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-x64, process-monitoring, process-monitor

I have an Application was compiled and I need list all directories he tries/have to access.

When I execute this App he returns with error message and I believe this is a permission error.

I already see the Process Explorer, but he don't show all files manipulated by Process/Application.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides [Process monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) (from [sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795535.aspx)) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx) (also from Sysinternals).
Handle application must run elevated (administrator)

```
handle -p myproc
```

Will return all handles for processes begin with the 'myproc'.

```
handle -pid 1234
```

Will return all handles for process with pid 1234.

Answer (score 0):

A nice utility here: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/process_activity_view.html
did the trick for me.

Open the ProcessActivityView.exe
Select "File"->"Start New Proces"
Then enter the path for your executable and program arguments if you need.
Checking "Start tracing immediately" box did not work for me.
This program attaches to the process and hooks to common syscalls for file access.